# Wait set time before completing action, loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write some code so that when a text box contains the text "true" my game will start my script Autoclickers, When this script runs i want it to check the 4 text boxes, if they contain true, wait a set time, increase points by certain amount, and then start over. The script should increase points every 3, 10, 15 and 25 seconds.
I have tried the Following and a few other things:

```
void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitI2());
}

public IEnumerator WaitI2()
{
    int.TryParse(Balance.text, out Amount);
    Points = 100;

    if (Item2Data.text == "true")
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(3);
        Amount += Points * 5;
    }

    Balance.text = Amount.ToString();
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(3);
}
```

Any help or explanation of where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see anything weird in your script, what is your script doing and what is it that it should be doing?

Comment: Currently the script waits at the start, then proceeds to continue forever increasing balance, i need it to wait before running again.